# Content Security Policy - Twitter Embedded Video

Tags: twitter, embed, content-security-policy

I have an embedded twitter video in a webview in a mobile app (Titanium, but this doesn't really matter). When I click play on the video I see this error:

> Refused to display '[the url]' in a frame because an ancestor violates
>   the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors *".

What is causing this issue is the fact that the webview content is being populated via a Hogan template that is loaded in from a local file path. I get the same error if I just copy the embed code into a file on my desktop and open the file in Chrome. It works fine in a webview in iOS and the local file works okay in Firefox, so this seems to be Chrome related.

1. Why is this failing with a wildcard for frame-ancestors?
2. Is there a way around this in my current setup?

Comment: If loading the template from the filesystem is the problem, you could try to add `filesystem:` to your frame-ancestors like so: `frame-ancestors * filesystem:` See the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors#Syntax) for further info...

Comment: Unfortunately thie CSP is defined in the response headers of a twitter embed url so I can't modify it.